# The property cannot be configured as navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to implement a domain model like this:
[image: My model]

This is an entity framework mvc application. The code for the model looks like this:

```
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    public int LoginID { get; set; }

    public virtual Therapist Therapist { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Login")]
    [Display(Name = "No.")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Therapist")]
    public int TherapistId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Therapist")]
    public int TherapistId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Therapist Therapist { get; set; }

    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }
}

public class Therapist
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Login")]
    [Display(Name = "No.")]
    public int TherapistId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Login")]
    public int LoginId { get; set; }

    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

I follow exactly what is in the tutorials and stack overflow questions, and no matter what I do, when I try to run the controller, I get the same error:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Patient'. The property "TherapistId"
>   cannot be configured as navigation property. The property must be a
>   valid entity type and the property should have non-abstract getter and
>   setter. For collection properties the type must implement
>   ICollection where T is a valid entity type

I have no idea what is wrong with `TherapistId` - maybe the whole idea of the model is rubbish?

Comment: In your `Patient` class you are attaching the `Therapist` ForeignKey to `LoginId`. I think you want that on `TherapistId` instead.

Comment: Also, you can remove all of those extra properties for the purpose of this question. It would make it much easier to read and understand.

Comment: 1. I changed it, still does not help 2. of course, sorry for that.

Comment: This model seems to have multiple issues, but try replacing the Login.TherapistId attribute with `[ForeignKey("Therapist")]`

Comment: well, it does not really help.

Comment: What is the controller code that throws this error?

Comment: @Jasen there is no code since there is no controller - I try to add a controller class using entity framework tools - and it's impossible cause the error is thrown when I try to do it

Answer (score 21):

I think your specific error in this case is that you have

```
[ForeignKey("TherapistId")]
public int? TherapistId { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
[ForeignKey("Therapist")]
public int? TherapistId { get; set; }
```

---

In any event, you do seem to have a few problems, maybe something like this (I only preserved relationship properties):

```
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    public int LoginID { get; set; }

    public virtual Therapist Therapist { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Login")]
    [Display(Name = "No.")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }

    // was this supposed to be optional?
    [ForeignKey("Therapist")]
    public int? TherapistId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Therapist Therapist { get; set; }
  }

public class Therapist
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Login")]
    [Display(Name = "No.")]
    public int TherapistId { get; set; }
    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

Usually, for one-to-one relationships in EF, both sides of the relationship must have the same primary key.

---

In fact, for what you're doing, maybe you could try using inheritance of some sort between `Login`, `Patient`, and `Therapist`, because at the moment, a `Login` could have both a `Patient` and `Therapist`.

Comment: I did exactly what is here - didn't help. All the time the problem is TherapistId.

Comment: "In fact, for what you're doing, maybe you could try using inheritance of some sort between Login, Patient, and Therapist, because at the moment, a Login could have both a Patient and Therapist." - I think this is what I will do.

Comment: @Tomek: I'm not sure why you're still getting your original error, then. Maybe you could try adding `[InverseProperty("Therapist")]` to `Therapist.Patients`

Comment: @Tomek: I created a test project and tried the code, seems to work fine. Maybe you have an outdated reference somewhere? As in this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013313/the-property-cannot-be-configured-as-a-navigation-property

Comment: Five bucks says the issue was that they weren't rebuilding the project between attempts at generating the controller